# Spawn a process in electron

Tags: electron, child-process, spawn

I have seen some posts about the topic,yes,it run very well when I used electron command in console.But it couldn't work when I packaged(electron-builder) the electron app,and appeared a problem when I started the app: it was starting create new process constantly,therefore there were a lot of processes in task manager we can see and CPU usage came to 100%.
I don't know how dose this happened, could you help me? please!
Here is my test code:

*master.js(main):*

```js
var childProcess = require('child_process');
let createProc = () => {
  let sp = childProcess.spawn(process.execPath, ['./go.js'], {stdio:'ignore'});
  sp.unref();
  sp.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('failed to start process',err);
  });
  sp.on('exit',(code, signal) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    createProc();
  });
}

createProc();
```

*go.js:*

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let basicWindowParams = {
  show: true,
  autoHideMenuBar:true
};
console.log(process.execPath)
console.log(process.execArgv)
console.log(process.pid)
app.on('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow(basicWindowParams);
  win.loadURL('http://www.reddit.com/');
  win.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.show();
  });
});
```

OS： Windows 10

Electron: 1.8.1

Update: I have created a repo for demonstration: https://github.com/xzycn/el_test

Comment: Is there someone can help me ? :(

Answer (score 0):

In the main electron file you can use something like this:

```
let serverProc = require('child_process').fork(
  require.resolve('./server.js'),
  ['--key', 'value'], // pass to process.argv into child
  {
    // options
  }
)
serverProc.on('exit', (code, sig) => {
  // finishing
})
serverProc.on('error', (error) => {
  // error handling
})
```